# jQuery multiple nested sortable lists - How to add another list so that its sortable too

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Looking for a little advice on how best to do the following:

I have 3 list items which can be ordered between each other, the top two then have one inner list each with items that can also be ordered, as well as dragged into a different inner list.

When I dynamically add a inner list to the 3rd outer list item, the sortable elements don't work for the new appended list.

Here's some code:

```
<ul id="outer_list">
  <li>
    <span class="handle"></span> List 1
    <ul class="inner_list">
      <li><span class="handle"></span> Title</li>
      <li><span class="handle"></span> Title</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span class="handle"></span> List 1
    <ul class="inner_list">
      <li><span class="handle"></span> Title</li>
      <li><span class="handle"></span> Title</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span class="handle"></span> List 1
  </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
// Outer lists
$( '#outer_list' ).sortable({
  handle: '.handle'
});


// Inner lists lists
var inner_list = $( '.inner_list' ).sortable({
  handle: '.handle',
  connectWith: '.inner_list'
});
```

I've tried doing the following, but no luck.

```
  inner_list.sortable( 'refresh' );
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try calling sortable on the dynamically appended inner list?

Comment: Yes, that does work, but I was hoping that it was possible to just use refresh in some way and just re-pickup all lists with the class (including the new one.)

Comment: You wish to combine the initialization and the updating in one step? You can try $( '.inner_list' ).sortable( 'refresh' );, but my gut says that the refresh method will not create any new "sortables", only things that have already had sortable applied.

Comment: Where is the code that does the injection? Was the injected thingy sortable before injecting?